# I'm starting to create a react app with Git bash but I there is an error I don't know if I set up my Git incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Here's the error what should I do ? TIA

```
`Error: Cannot find module './lib/pack.js'
`Require stack:
 - C:\Users\ederlyn.j.marasigan\AppData\Local\npm-        cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\tar\tar.js
- C:\Users\ederlyn.j.marasigan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\tar-    pack\index.js
- C:\Users\ederlyn.j.marasigan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js
- C:\Users\ederlyn.j.marasigan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ederlyn.j.marasigan\AppData\Local\npm-   cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\tar\tar.js:171:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
'C:\\Users\\ederlyn.j.marasigan\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\tar\\tar.js',
'C:\\Users\\ederlyn.j.marasigan\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\tar-pack\\index.js',
'C:\\Users\\ederlyn.j.marasigan\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\create-react-app\\createReactApp.js',
'C:\\Users\\ederlyn.j.marasigan\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\create-react-app\\index.js'
```

]
}

```
Node.js v18.16.0``
```

I want to follow the instructions and steps from the course I'm currently taking to set up my react

Comment: any wrong or missing in package.json?